# How can you change the table of contents line spacing in Quarto when rendering to a PDF?

Tags: pdf, yaml, latex, quarto

I am using Quarto for my dissertation and wish to change the table of contents line spacing to 1 when rendering to a PDF. I have my line spacing for the rest of the document set to 1.5 using `linestretch: 1.5`.

I have tried making up commands such as `toc-linestretch: 1.5`, which has not worked for me. From the [basic documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/pdf.html#table-of-contents), I don't see how to change the `toc` spacing to 1 and keep the rest of the document spacing to 1.5. If anyone knows how to do this within the _quarto.yml file, please let me know!

I have also tried to make a custom toc.text file as a [LaTeX/template partial](https://quarto.org/docs/journals/templates.html#template-partials), but so far it's not working. I based my toc.tex file on the defaul template provided in the [Quarto source code](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/src/resources/formats/pdf/pandoc/template.tex) (scroll to line ~337). My current toc.tex file is:

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1}
$if(has-frontmatter)$
\mainmatter
$endif$
$body$
```

I expected `\setstretch{1}` to work, but this is my first experience with LaTeX, so I wouldn't be surprised if my toc.tex file has issues, but I'm not sure what to try next. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `toc.tex` file you have provided here doesn't contain the necessary command (`\tableofcontents`) to generate the table of contents and you don't need to use the [`template.tex`](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/src/resources/formats/pdf/pandoc/template.tex) if you just need to modify the toc, you may use just the [`toc.tex`](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/blob/main/src/resources/formats/pdf/pandoc/toc.tex) instead.

So you can try to use the following `toc.tex` file (which I have modified a bit by removing lines for `beamer` format)

**toc.tex**

```
{\setstretch{1} % set the linestrech from here ------------------------
$if(toc)$
$if(toc-title)$
\renewcommand*\contentsname{$toc-title$}
$endif$
$if(colorlinks)$
\hypersetup{linkcolor=$if(toccolor)$$toccolor$$else$$endif$}
$endif$
\setcounter{tocdepth}{$toc-depth$}
\tableofcontents
$endif$
} % upto here ---------------------------------------------------------

$if(lof)$
\listoffigures
$endif$
$if(lot)$
\listoftables
$endif$
```

And then put the `\usepackage{setspace}` under `include-in-header` yaml key in the `_quarto.yml` file.

**_quarto.yml**

```
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "Book"
  author: "Jane Doe"
  date: "1/4/2023"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
    - intro.qmd
    - summary.qmd
    - references.qmd

bibliography: references.bib

format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrreprt
    linestretch: 1.5
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \usepackage{setspace}
    template-partials: 
      - toc.tex
```